# Disappearing div in IE

Tags: css

I have a site where there is a div with float on the menu and I have a hover property in CSS that changes the border, when I do a mouseout the divs below disappear.
Please click in the poker page and there do mouse out and mouse in
Site for casinos
[Ruleta](http://www.ganealaruleta.com)

Comment: Next time, try to be more specific of your problem and include sample code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the [Guillotine Bug](http://css-class.com/articles/explorer/guillotine/#).  It's a bug in IE6 and IE7 that occurs when certain mixtures of :hover, float, and layout are present (see link for details).  One way to fix it would be to insert the following after the last #menuItem (as the last child of #mainItems):

```
<div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
```

and then apply the following CSS to it:

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

On a side note, I would suggest changing most of the id hooks you have to class hooks (eg.`<div class="menuItems">`) because it is conventional to have a unique id for each element.